# IIS8 new security implementation?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-8

What are the new security feature introduced in IIS8?
I have one web app. I need to host that app in the IIS8 but If I put that app in C drive I am not getting the data..but the same worked with IIS6..???

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 and IIS8 both use ApplicationPoolIdentity which is a virtual windows account. You can add this user to the NTFS permissions of your webroot by manually typing in "IIS AppPool\apppoolname" Replace apppoolname with the actual name of the application pool.